# NSmutableDictionary adding unwanted characters

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary set out like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
data[@"username"] = username;
data[@"password"] = password;
data[@"timestamp"] = timestr;
data[@"req"] = STATIC_TOKEN;
data[@"version"] = @"7.0.2";
```

but when it runs instead of getting

```
req:12345-324-3
```

I get

```
"req":12345-324-3.
```

But it only happens with the req line. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: what is your STATIC_TOKEN?

Comment: Are you referring simply to the log output?  Don't pay attention to it, it is arbitrary.

Comment: This happens when the value contains non-alphanumeric characters. That's how the description method works. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: The STATIC_TOKEN is a generated string. It's not only the log output, this data gets posted and its posting the extra "" which is causing errors.

Comment: But its not putting the "" around the STATIC_TOKEN just the req Aditya?

Comment: I saw this on reddit. I'd like to side with Aditya on this one.

Comment: @MattMcInnes What kind of error are you getting because of the ""? Because it is just the name of the key in the dictionary. The "" doesnt actually play any role there.